# Exception while retriving OpenTok Session object in with play framework

Tags: java, opentok, playframework-2.4

I am createing the session as mentioned in  Tokbox [documetation](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/java/)
using play framework. My code is as follows..

```
OpenTok opentok = new OpenTok(ApiCredentials.apiKey, ApiCredentials.apiSecret);Session session = null;
    try {


        session = opentok.createSession();
    } catch (OpenTokException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

session = opentok.createSession(); this line is giving the following exception

```
[ERROR] [07/13/2015 01:55:16.570] [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10] [ActorSystem(application)] Uncaught fatal error from thread [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10] shutting down ActorSystem [application]java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient$BoundRequestBuilder.setParameters(Lcom/ning/http/client/FluentStringsMap;)Lcom/ning/http/client/AsyncHttpClient$BoundRequestBuilder;
at com.opentok.util.HttpClient.createSession(HttpClient.java:39)
at com.opentok.OpenTok.createSession(OpenTok.java:247)
at com.opentok.OpenTok.createSession(OpenTok.java:301)
at controllers.TokBoxController.createSession(TokBoxController.java:50)
at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$19$$anonfun$apply$19.apply(Routes.scala:768)
at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$19$$anonfun$apply$19.apply(Routes.scala:768)
at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:136)
at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$14$$anon$3$$anon$1.invocation(HandlerInvoker.scala:127)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:65)
at play.http.DefaultHttpRequestHandler$1.call(DefaultHttpRequestHandler.java:20)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:85)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:85)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:40)
at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70)
at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext.execute(HttpExecutionContext.scala:32)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$.apply(Future.scala:31)
at scala.concurrent.Future$.apply(Future.scala:492)
at play.core.j.JavaAction.apply(JavaAction.scala:85)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105)
at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:104)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:103)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:103)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:96)
at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524)
at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524)
at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560)
at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560)
at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:536)
at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:536)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

please help me.. i stuck like since one day

Comment: I created a stand alone application, and its working fine in that, i guess play is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a little bit long to me and moreover it wasn't the exact solution..
I couldn't understand the exact problem in play with the play libraries while integrating tok box api, so I used open [tok's rest api](https://tokbox.com/developer/rest/)  and integrate it in play application with [play WS api](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaWS). Thanks for help and support though.

Answer (score 0):

```
Redirect("/yourRedirectPage").withSession("storeSession" -> opentok)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: -

```
OpenTok opentok = new OpenTok(OPEN_TOK_API_KEY,OPEN_TOK_API_SECRET);
Session session = opentok.createSession(new SessionProperties.Builder()
              .mediaMode(MediaMode.ROUTED)
              .build());
```

and also recheck your "API_KEY" and "API_SECRET_KEY"

Comment: keys are correct... i mentioned in comment i am able to get session from stand alone application.